# Xamarin sample projects not compiling

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I just started to look at Xamarin and downloaded a prebuilt contacts sample app.

It does not compile in Visual Studio because it is full of strange syntax I never saw before, searching Google didnt fruit..

For eample, this is weird:

```
[JsonIgnore]
public string AddressString => string.Format(
    "{0} {1} {2} {3}", Street,
    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(City) ? City + "," : "",
    State, PostalCode);

[JsonIgnore]
public string DisplayName => ToString();

[JsonIgnore]
public string DisplayLastNameFirst => $"{LastName}, {FirstName}";

[JsonIgnore]
public string StatePostal => State + " " + PostalCode;

public override string ToString()
{
    return FirstName + " " + LastName;
}
```

These strange lambda expressions - what are they? Why are they not "="? And the $ signs? The .NET compiler spits them all out.

This is another one:

```
static int MatchScore(Acquaintance c, string query)
{
    return new[]
    {
        $"{c.FirstName} {c.LastName}",
        c.Email,
        c.Company,
    }.Sum(label => MatchScore(label, query));
}
```

The compiler says { and } are expected...

What did I miss in the last 5 years???

Answer (score 10):

The strange syntax that you see is C# 6 syntax. You will need to open the project in VS 2015 to compile it.

The first one with lambda expressions is [Expression Bodied Members](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2015/05/14/c.net-little-wonders-expression-bodied-members-in-c-6.aspx). You can rewrite the first example as

```
 public string AddressString 
 { 
    get 
    { 
        return string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}",
              Street, !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(City) ? City + "," : "",
              State, PostalCode);
    }
}
```

The second one with $ sign is [string interpolation](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2015/03/26/c.net-little-wonders-string-interpolation-in-c-6.aspx) and you can replace it with `string.Format`